# If my vector doesn't contain a construct how to set it to zero

Tags: c++, templates, vector, constructor

I get the no default constructor exists for class "vector" Error

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "myVector.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    vector<int> myvecA;
    cout << "Vector A size: " << myvecA.size() << endl;

system("Pause");
return 0;
}
```

myVector.h

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 template <class V>
 class vector{

public:
 vector(V x) {
    bool(x = 0)
        sizearr = 0;
    if (x != 0)
        return x;
    sizearr = x;

}

  V size();

private:

  V sizearr;

};

template <class V>

 V vector<V>::size() {
     return sizearr;
}
```

I don't know how to make it so that if

```
vector<int> myvecA;
```

doesn't contain a construct that it will set the construct to 0 so i can return size as 0.

I apologize if my question is not very clear. I'm just look for help so I can learn.I'm not very good at c++.

Comment: There is already `std::vector1`. The use [of the obnoxious "using namespace std"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and then declaring one's own `vector` just makes things confusing. You  need to completely forget that "using namespace std;" exists in C++. It's bad programming practice.

Comment: Wait, you're declaring your own `vector` class and you don't provide a default constructor? Just what the error message says? Why not simply use the `std::vector<int>` BTW?

Comment: `bool(x = 0) sizearr = 0;` is a syntax error. Your compilershould say something

Comment: Throw a handful of darts blindfolded, some will stick. You are templating without a fundamental understanding of classes. This is a very hard way to learn.

Comment: @M.M That depends on the compiler he's using.

Comment: @AmericanPatriot Trump's compiler is the only reliable one. Narrow enough to reflect their worlds view. Something like Turbo C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to provide a default constructor for the class

```
template <class V> class vector {

public:
 explicit vector(): sizearr(0) {}
}
```

Also, constructors do not "return" in the sense used for normal functions. A constructor initializes the internals of a class, the memory needed for the object of the class is created using either `new` keyword or allocated on the stack.

---

One more thing, you have to do is to prevent your class from interfering with existing classes (in this case `std::vector`). The way to do this is to remove that declaration of `using namespace std` from your header file. Having `using namespace std` will become a problem if you decide to include your header in a file that uses the standard `std::vector` in which case your new class will conflict with the already existing one or vice versa.

It is also good practice not to use `using namespace X` declarative because namespaces safeguard against naming conflicts, and exposing the names in the namespace is in direct conflict with the purpose of a namespace. The only recommended place to use `using namespace X` is when you are implementing functionality for a given namespace in a "private" .cpp file.

Hope that helps. Ask more questions

Comment: This would probably collide with `std::vector`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My assumption is that OP is not also using `#include <vector>` somewhere in their code

Comment: @smac89 any header may include any other header, so you can't rely on that. The fix is for OP to stop doing `using namespace std;`